# How to display a dynamic set of divs depending on how many indexes I have on an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, sorting

I'm creating the Wikipedia Viewer from FCC. I want to display a set of divs depending on how many values I have on an array. Something like this:

```
const arrayWithValues= ['1','2','3','4','5'];
```

So for each value on my array I want to have something like this:

```
//the key is passed as the index of the array
<div key={i}> content here </div>
<div key={i}> content here </div>
```

So I have seem it before using `map` but don't remember how to use it.

The thing is that I have an empty array, but after the user search with a given input. I make an api call and them the results are pushed into an array. I'm using react so I have that array on my state, I want to grab those values and be able to display them on the page inside a div (with a given className etc ... )

Comment: There are literally hundreds of posts and questions about this. This is very well documented question. Use Google to find your answer, and look at the documentation for `.map`, since you're saying that you have seen it before.

Comment: Please note with all the answers below, it is not a good idea to use the index alone as the key, and using the value alone only works if all values are unique. A combination of the two may be your best bet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use map like this to render the set of `div`

```
arrayWithValues.map((value, i) => {
 return (<div key={i}> content here </div>)
})
```

Comment: Where do you get `i` from ?

Answer (score 1):

Piyush's answer is on point. If you wanted to follow React architecture to the letter the end result would look something like this:

```
class ItemList extends React.Component {
  const arrayWithValues= ['1','2','3','4','5'];

  render() {
    let listOfValues = arrayWithValues.map((value) => {
      return (<Item arrayValue={ value } />)
    });

    return (
      {listOfValues}
    );
  }

}
export default ItemList;


class Item extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (<div key={this.props.arrayValue}> content here </div>);
  }
}
export default Item;
```

EDIT: I've adjusted this according to feedback.

Comment: You cannot pass key as a prop to child @joseph

Comment: @PiyushBhati out of curiosity, can you please explain this? `this.props.arrayValue` is just a passed down number, is it not?

Comment: It is! I just wanted an example that showed how to use `map` in the context of components.

Answer (score 0):

```
arrayWithValues.map((val, i) => (<div key={i}>content here</div>));
```

Comment: Some explanation would be helpful here!

Comment: What exactly is unclear?
 there is a lambda you pass to `map` function. You don't need  return keyword when you don't use curly braces, which means return is implied. Basically, for each pair of value and index, return a div with key equaling to i and text being `"content here"`